# Is there a numeric UpDown control for ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net

Is there a way I can use a numeric updown in ASP.NET without using JavaScript?

And if not, is there an alternative?

Comment: alternative to what problem? What do you mean with "without using Javascript?" plain HTML? There is none: http://tjvantoll.com/2012/07/15/native-html5-number-picker-vs-jquery-uis-spinner-which-to-use/

Comment: @CasparKleijne alternative way of getting this type of control without using Javascript

Comment: I have a field called Quantity in my web form. A textbox would require a lot of validators to ensure it's numeric so I thought a numeric updown object is more user-friendly for the interface and the code. Any alternative to the updown object? other than a textbox?

Comment: @LukeHennerly, ASP.NET resides heavily on javascript.

Answer (score 31):

I was trying to do the same thing, and it turns out the asp textbox has an option for it. what worked for me was this:

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Number" runat="server" min="0" max="20" step="1"/>
```

this gave me a textbox which, when mouse hovers over it or is given focus, shows the up-down controls, and only allows numbers from min to max.
it works the same as

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="20" step="1" />
```

Comment: [TextMode values like `Number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode(v=vs.110).aspx) are available in version 4.5 (not 4) of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 5):

Please look into the Ajax Control Toolkit

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx

```
<ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NUD1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
    Width="100"
    RefValues="January;February;March;April"
    TargetButtonDownID="Button1"
    TargetButtonUpID="Button2"
    ServiceDownPath="WebService1.asmx"
    ServiceDownMethod="PrevValue"
    ServiceUpPath="WebService1.asmx"
    ServiceUpMethod="NextValue"
    Tag="1" />
```

Also consider adding the reference with [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/) by using `PM> Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit`

Comment: -1 The OP explicitly needs a solution without using javascript. This solution requires javascript.

Comment: @CasparKleijne At what point does the code above use javascript? It is pure HTML and probably the best/only solution available to him. The underlying code may use javascript however the solution does not, I would say the main reason the OP didn't want to use javascript is because they don't understand it not because they can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following html can answer your question:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Numeric Up Down</title>
    <script type="text/jscript">
        function Load() {
           /*numericUpDown1.value = or*/ document.getElementById("numericUpDown1").value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%=NumericUpDown1.ClientID%>").value);
        }
        function Change() {
           document.getElementById("<%=NumericUpDown1.ClientID%>").value = document.getElementById("numericUpDown1").value; //or numericUpDown1.value
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Load()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <input type="number" id="numericUpDown1" onchange="Change()" />
       <asp:HiddenField ID="NumericUpDown1" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

And then on the asp server side code in C# or Visual Basic, you can treat that HiddenField as NumericUpDown, but **note** that his value is **string**, and **not** decimal, like System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown control, or float, or double, or int, so you will have to Parse it to one of these types for what you need the most.

If you want to **style** the numeric up down, then in javascript it is simple. Just set document.getElementById("numericUpDown1").style, but if you want to do it through the asp server side code in C# or Visual Basic, then the html **must** be different:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Numeric Up Down</title>
    <script type="text/jscript">
        function Change() {
           document.getElementById("<%=NumericUpDown1.ClientID%>").value = document.getElementById("numericUpDown1").value; //or numericUpDown1.value
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <% this.Response.Write(string.Format("<input type='number' id='numericUpDown1' value='{0}' onchange='Change()' style='{1}' />", this.NumericUpDown1.Value, this.numericUpDown1Style)); %>
       <asp:HiddenField ID="NumericUpDown1" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

**numericUpDown1Style** is a protected field whose type is **string** defined in the asp server side code in C# or Visual Basic.

If you want to give it a **class** and not to style it, then the html must be:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Numeric Up Down</title>
    <script type="text/jscript">
        function Change() {
           document.getElementById("<%=NumericUpDown1.ClientID%>").value = document.getElementById("numericUpDown1").value; //or numericUpDown1.value
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <% this.Response.Write(string.Format("<input type='number' id='numericUpDown1' value='{0}' onchange='Change()' class='{1}' />", this.NumericUpDown1.Value, this.numericUpDown1CssClass)); %>
       <asp:HiddenField ID="NumericUpDown1" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

**numericUpDown1CssClass** is a protected field whose type is **string** defined in the asp server side code in C# or Visual Basic.

If you want to style it and give it a class, then html is like html #2 or html #3, but the only change is in the following line:

```
<% this.Response.Write(string.Format("<input type='number' id='numericUpDown1' value='{0}' onchange='Change()' style='{1}' class='{2}' />", this.NumericUpDown1.Value, this.numericUpDown1Style, this.numericUpDown1CssClass)); %>
```

I think you know what is **numericUpDown1Style** and **numericUpDown1CssClass** from #2 and #3

**RECOMMENDED TIP:**

If your website contains a lot of numeric up down controls that are used in your asp server side code, and this is disadvantageous to create all of them this way, then you can add new "Web User Control" item to your website and name it "NumericUpDown". Then in its source html you can copy the html #1 or html #2 or html #3 or html #4 that I posted above (depends on if you want to style the numeric up down or not, or give it a class or not, or both or not) with some removes and changes, because it is not "WebForm", but "Web User Control"
and in the asp server side code make the following properties (They are in C#, but if you use Visual Basic, I don't think it will be a problem for you to translate the code):

```
    public decimal Value
    {
        get
        {
            return decimal.Parse(this.HiddenField.Value);
        }
        set
        {
            this.HiddenField.Value = value.ToString();
        }
    }
    //Like the System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown.Value, but if you dislike 'decimal', and you want other type, then you can change the return type and the type Parse.
//Note that the ID of the HiddenField is simply "HiddenField", and not "NumericUpDown1", so make sure in the Source html to rename "NumericUpDown1" to "HiddenField", but probably you would like a different ID, so if you gave it different ID, then ensure that in the code you refer this HiddenField with the ID you chose, and not "HiddenField" or "NumericUpDown1".

    //The following properties are for only if you want to style your Numeric Up Down:
    protected string style;
    public string Style
    {
        get
        {
            return this.style;
        }
        set
        {
            this.style = value;
        }
    }
    //If you chose, copied, pasted and changed html #2 or html #4, then don't forget to replace this.numericUpDown1Style to this.Style in the source html of the Web User Control.
    //Optional
    public Unit Width
    {
       get
       {
           int startIndex = this.style.IndexOf("width") + 6;
           if (index != -1)
           {
               int endIndex = this.style.IndexOf(';', startIndex);
               return Unit.Parse(this.style.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));
           }
           return Unit.Empty;
       }
       set
       {
          if (this.style.Contains("width"))
          {
              this.style = this.style.Replace("width:" + this.Width.ToString() + ';', "width:" + value.ToString() + ';');
          }
          else
          {
              this.style += "width:" + value.ToString() + ';';
          }
       }
    }
//The same you can do with the Height property.
//You can replace all the style code with the CssClass code instead, or just add it:
protected string cssClass;
public string CssClass
{
    get
    {
        return this.cssClass;
    }
    set
    {
        this.cssClass = value;
    }
}
    //If you chose, copied, pasted and changed html #3 or html #4, then don't forget to replace this.numericUpDown1CssClass to this.CssClass in the source html of the Web User Control.
```

If you style the NumericUpDown, so know also that in every ASP.NET control, you can type after their ID .Style["style"] = "value".

If you want to be able to do this with NumericUpDown too, then change the type of the protected field **style** from **string** to **MyStyle**

There is the definition of **MyStyle**:

```
public class MyStyle
{
    internal string style;
    public string this[string style]
    {
        get
        {
            int startIndex = this.style.IndexOf(style) + style.Length + 1;
            int endIndex = this.style.IndexOf(';', startIndex);
            return this.style.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)
        }
        set
        {
            this.style = this.style.Replace(style + ':' + this[style] + ';', style + ':' + value + ';')
        }
    }
}
```

Add this class to the Code of the Web User Control, and change the Style property:

```
public string Styles
{
    get
    {
        return this.style.style;
    }
    set
    {
        this.style.style = value;
    }
}
```

and then add the property:

```
public MyStyle Style
{
    get
    {
        return this.style;
    }
}
```

and change the line from:

```
protected string style;
```

to:

```
protected readonly MyStyle style = new MyStyle();
```

Don't forget in the source html of Web User Control, to replace this.Style to this.Styles.

**NOTE**: I didn't had patience to test the code by myself, so it might not work, so you'll have to fix it by yourself. 
At least you understood my idea.

After the fixes, you can edit my answer and replace the wrong code with your fixed code.

I will appreciate it very much!

This Web User Control is the ASP NumericUpDown you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck on .NET 4.0 and you want to use the native HTML5 input type "number" (rather than the NumericUpDown from Ajax Control Toolkit) you can use a combination of the ASP TextBox control with extra "type" tag:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMyTextBox" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="1"/>
```

If you want to prevent any text input, you could even add a FilteredTextBoxExtender from Ajax Control Toolkit:

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="txtMyTextBox" FilterType="Numbers" />
```